# How to create RPM package that uses setcap and works on both dnf/yum (fedora/redhat) and zypper (openSuse)

Tags: yum, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, dnf, zypper

I'm developing an RPM package for a service that requires the command `setcap` for setting capabilities. The purpose of using `setcap` is to listen to port numbers below 1024.

RPM packages have a 'Requires' section that is a comma-separated list of other required packages, and in theory I can use that to make sure the target system installs the packages needed.

Now here's the problem:

- `setcap` is available for Fedora in package `libcap` and for openSUSE in package `libcap-progs`.
- the package `libcap` is not available on openSUSE, and `libcap-progs` is not available on Fedora.

Is it possible to create a single RPM package that installs `setcap` and works on both Fedora and openSUSE?

Comment: I've usually seen RPMs built for a specific distro. The source specfile can have something keying off of `%{dist}` or a similar variable, but you would still need to build for each distro specifically.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to write the following:

Requires: /usr/sbin/setcap

This will resolve on both Fedora and openSUSE to their corresponding library